# pandas apply individual logic to group

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
day id  val
1-Jan   A   -5
2-Jan   A   -4
3-Jan   A   3
1-Jan   B   2
2-Jan   B   1
3-Jan   B   -5
```

how can i add a new column where, for all rows with the same id, if val was negative on 1-Jan, all rows are "Y" and "N" if not? something like this:

```
day id  val neg_on_jan_1
1-Jan   A   -5  y
2-Jan   A   -4  y
3-Jan   A   3   y
1-Jan   B   2   n
2-Jan   B   1   n
3-Jan   B   -5  n
```

I've looked at group by and apply-lambda functions but still feel like i'm missing something. I'm just starting out with pandas, coming from a background in SQL, so please forgive me if my brain still thinks in rows and Oracle analytic functions :)

Comment: IIUC then `df['neg_on_jan_1'] = np.where(df[df['day id == '1-Jan']].groupby('id')['val'].transform(lambda x: x < 0), 'y', 'n')` should work

Comment: @EdChum It looks like you have a typo (`'day id` seems unterminated; also, not sure what you meant there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Included `map` per @Ami Tavory's suggestion

```
gb = df.set_index(['day', 'id']).groupby(level='id')
s = gb.val.transform(lambda s: s.loc['1-Jan'].lt(0)).map({1: 'y', 0:'n'})
s

day    id
1-Jan  A     y
2-Jan  A     y
3-Jan  A     y
1-Jan  B     n
2-Jan  B     n
3-Jan  B     n
Name: val, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.merge(s.to_frame('neg_on_jan_1').reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: @AmiTavory I was editing as you commented.  I like `map` better.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what i needed. Can you explain what it's doing?